# Downloading Yfinance fundamental data. TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm trying to download stock fundamental data from yahoo finance using yfinance library

```
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf 
symbol = 'AAPL'
ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
ticker.income_stmt
```

But then i get
TypeError: string indices must be integers

I tried several solution that i found in the Internet

```
import pandas as pd

tickers_list = ["aapl"] # example list
tickers_data= {} # empty dictionary
for ticker in tickers_list:
    ticker_object = yf.Ticker(ticker)

    #convert info() output from dictionary to dataframe
    temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ticker_object.info, orient="index")
    temp.reset_index(inplace=True)
    temp.columns = ["Attribute", "Recent"]
    
    # add (ticker, dataframe) to main dictionary
    tickers_data[ticker] = temp

tickers_data
```

But anyway nothing helped...

I'm just starting learning python and maybe i made silly mistake. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: "_But then i get TypeError: string indices must be integers_" On which line of code?

Comment: 1 symbol = 'AAPL'
      2 ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
----> 3 ticker.income_stmt

Comment: @Maksim Format the code properly in comments, you're getting an error on line 3 at `ticker.income_stmt`? I do not get any error.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem in the last few days. You probably have yfinance version 0.2.3. Try to update yfinance to version 0.2.4. It worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I only had to update to version 0.2.35, but all seems to be fixed.